# voice_channel.play() plays no audio

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I recently decided to learn discord.py library and I was trying to make a music bot. When I use the "play" command it doesn't raise any errors but doesn't play any audio either. Also after using "play" if use the "pause", "stop" and "resume" commands I get an error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

The code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.vc = None

    @commands.command(name="join",help="Müzük açmadan önce kanala katılırım.")
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}Şu anda bir ses kanalında değilsin.")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}Şu anda başka bir ses kanalındayım.")
        print(ctx.voice_client.is_playing())

    @commands.command(name="disconnect",help="Kanaldan çıkıp giderim.")
    async def disconnect(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command(name="play",aliases =['p'],help="YouTube linkini alıp oynatırım.")
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5','options':'vnd'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url,download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        vc.play(source)
        await ctx.send("Şu anda şarkını çalıyorum.")
    @commands.command(name = "pause",help="Müzüğü durdururum.")
    async def pause(self,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("Müzik durduruldu")

    @commands.command(name="stop",help="Müzük kapanır")
    async def stop(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.stop()
        await ctx.send("Müzüğü kapattım.")

    @commands.command(name = "resume",help="Müzüğü devam ettiririm.")
    async def resume(self,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("Müzik devam ediyor")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so apparently 'options':''vnd' makes it so that there will be no audio playing for some reason. Changing 'vnd' to '-vn' just solved the audio issue.

As for the errors, I just deleted the await commands in "stop","pause" and "resume". So the working code looks something like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.vc = None

    @commands.command(name="join",help="Müzük açmadan önce kanala katılırım.")
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}Şu anda bir ses kanalında değilsin.")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}Şu anda başka bir ses kanalındayım.")

    @commands.command(name="disconnect",help="Kanaldan çıkıp giderim.")
    async def disconnect(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command(name="play",aliases =['p'],help="YouTube linkini alıp oynatırım.")
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url,download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        vc.play(source)
        await ctx.send("Şu anda şarkını çalıyorum.")
    @commands.command(name = "pause",help="Müzüğü durdururum.")
    async def pause(self,ctx):
        ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("Müzik durduruldu")

    @commands.command(name="stop",help="Müzük kapanır")
    async def stop(self, ctx):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        await ctx.send("Müzüğü kapattım.")

    @commands.command(name = "resume",help="Müzüğü devam ettiririm.")
    async def resume(self,ctx):
        ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("Müzik devam ediyor")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! The main problem is that you do not have your code indented the right way. Your commands need to be indented so it will be part of the cog file. The updated code should be..

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.vc = None

    @commands.command(name="join",help="Müzük açmadan önce kanala katılırım.")
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}Şu anda bir ses kanalında değilsin.")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}Şu anda başka bir ses kanalındayım.")
        print(ctx.voice_client.is_playing())

    @commands.command(name="disconnect",help="Kanaldan çıkıp giderim.")
    async def disconnect(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command(name="play",aliases =['p'],help="YouTube linkini alıp oynatırım.")
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5','options':'vnd'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url,download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        vc.play(source)
        await ctx.send("Şu anda şarkını çalıyorum.")
    @commands.command(name = "pause",help="Müzüğü durdururum.")
    async def pause(self,ctx):
            await ctx.voice_client.pause()
            await ctx.send("Müzik durduruldu")

    @commands.command(name="stop",help="Müzük kapanır")
    async def stop(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.stop()
        await ctx.send("Müzüğü kapattım.")

    @commands.command(name = "resume",help="Müzüğü devam ettiririm.")
    async def resume(self,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("Müzik devam ediyor")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Everything else looks fine to me but I don't use the youtube-dl library so if there any more errors, just tell me :D Also, this should fix the TypeError error as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The code was already indented when I wrote it. I accidentaly did not indent them correctly when I was posting here. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @SAM So is your problem still occuring?

Comment: Yeah it was but I just found out that **FFMPEG_OPTIONS was breaking the player.  Turns out 'options':'vnd' just doesn't work.